# Website constructed using a JS application no longer indexed as per google's AJAX Crawling spec. Whats the issue?

Tags: seo, google, ajax

I have two sites that should be compliant to googles AJAX Crawling spec (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) .

One domain (http://auroraliveaboard.com) was previously indexed, and now lost all search results.
Another domain (http://acs-germany.de) never got indexed, and after complying with the spec for a month and a half nothing has changed, and no results show up.

My application contains links in using the #! format, which are made in the following format:

```
http://tld.com/#!locale/page
```

a rewrite rule is in place to serve the correct HTML snapshot targeting requests for:

```
http://tld.com/?_escaped_fragment_=locale/page
```

This snapshot is generated by simply dumping the DOM to a nodeJS instance, and wrapping the outputted HTML within new tags.

It becomes obvious at this point that there is no cloaking going on, as i'm simply dumping the DOM for each page, verbatim as a browser with JS enabled sees it.

The reasoning for using an JS app instead of static pages is not part of this discussion.

I'm concerned with the reason, and a possible solution, to why google is no longer indexing the pages. I am pretty sure that i am in full compliance with the spec.
I've submitted a sitemap containing all the links as well. Nothing changed. The sitemap is present as "sitemap.txt" for both domains.

If somebody could help shed some light on the issue i'd be very grateful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the auroraliveaboard.com and acs-germany.de sites do not implement correctly  the [AJAX crawling scheme from Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) you described.

Regarding auroraliveaboard.com, it seems escaped fragment URLs always return the same content. For example http://auroraliveaboard.com/?_escaped_fragment_=en_routes does not return a snapshot of http://auroraliveaboard.com/#!en_routes.

Regarding acs-germany.de, the rewriting rule does not work sometimes. For example, http://acs-germany.de/?_escaped_fragment_=en/news redirects to http://acs-germany.de/snapshots/en/news.html which does not exist.
It seems also you renamed the "fragments" path to "snapshots". [As you can see](https://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Aacs-germany.de%2Ffragments) Google indexed some of these presumed old pages but also tried to get snapshots by using the redirected URL (e.g. http://acs-germany.de/fragments/de/news.html#!en/news instead of http://acs-germany.de/#!en/news). It may explain why it did not work.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking into the rewrite rules on auroraliveaboard.com , there seems to be something odd about that, indeed.

Comment: Regarding acs-germany.de , i did rename fragments to snapshots, because google had indexed the files submitted via sitemap but i had forgotten the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> meta tag. i added that, and since the google index was corrupted [it was indexing wrong links which broke the app] i made the folder name change and adjusted the rewrite rules accordingly.

Comment: I also received a hint from another user that i might not be respecting the spec 100% because the spec says "#!key=value" and i, essentially, only have "#!value"

Comment: You are not forced to use `key=value` format. See this doc: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992.